# Performing an event at the base form level

Tags: c#, winforms

This seems fairly simple, but I haven't been able to accomplish it.  I have a BaseForm class that every form in my application inherits.

I simply want to execute a line of code every time a key is pressed in any form inheriting the BaseForm.  In my BaseForm I've attempted the following with no luck:

```
public class BaseForm : Form
{
     protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
     {
          //Perform action
     }

}

public class MainForm : BaseForm
{
     //All of my main form code goes here.
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to set `KeyPreview` of your base form to `true` for it to be able catch all the key presses from any control. Consider doing this in the form designer or in the base class constructor. I guess you've got some editors (a textbox, for example) on your derived forms, so you need the `KeyPreview` to be set to `true` for the base form to be able to catch those key presses.

You can either override the `OnKeyPress` method (as in your question) or add an event handler for the `KeyPress` event in the base form.

```
public class BaseForm : Form
{
     public BaseForm()
     {
         this.KeyPreview = true; //it's necessary!! 

         //or just override the OnKeyPress method instead
         this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(BaseForm_KeyPress);
     }

     private void BaseForm_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
     {
         //do your action
     }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Setting the KeyPreview to true forced it to catch.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

What you have done so far is correct. If your OnKeyPress is not being executed then you have something wrong - do you have an OnKeyDown that is interfering?

What you do next is to have the same override in your derived forms:

```
public class MainForm : BaseForm
{
     //All of my main form code goes here.

     protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
     {
          //do whatever action this form needs to, if any

          base.OnKeyPress(e);
     }
}
```

See that call to the `base.OnKeyPress`? That executes that line of code you have in the base. Note that you can put that call anywhere within the function, it might be more appropriate to have it at the start before the form specific code.

Comment: You're exactly right, but unfortunately this application has 100s of forms and would be extremely time consuming to add KeyPress events to each form.  Thanks!